# How to fix broken system icons in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, icons

This is what my settings app looks like:

[image: Windows Settings]

and this is what the beginning of my start menu looks like (all the tiles and app/program shortcuts look normal):

[image: Start Menu]

Icons are also missing (replaced with the same empty square box) from context menus, e.g. when right-clicking on the desktop.

I have tried various things to fix it to no avail, including setting up a local user account to test if it was account related (which it is not), and resetting the icon cache (which made no difference).

It happened after "cleaning" the registry using a popular such tool. Apparently not a wise decision and there was no way to restore the registry, not even with a system restore. Apart from this, all other icons work fine. Does anyone know how this can be fixed relatively easily, or do I need to re-install Windows?

Comment: I completely agree with @Ramhound !  Scenarios like this one need to serve as a valuable lesson for the future.  Folks, **please** don't used automated registry cleaning utilities!  There is *very* little value added to using one, and the potential consequences can be disastrous!  As he said, you can do a [Reset](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4130-reset-windows-10-a.html) or [Refresh](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4090-refresh-windows-10-a.html) with one of these tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment and for the links! Yes, a valuable lesson has been learned. :)